# Is there a way to add text in selected date slot on FullCalendar without triggering the popup?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I'm trying to use the selectable dates feature in FullCalendar but I'd like to add some text in the clicked slot without triggering the popup alert with text input field.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes of course. The alert box is not part of fullCalendar. You can add some text directly, or you can ask the user for their input in some other way

Comment: ADyson, I've tried to do what you suggested but wasn't able to add data in the box without getting the alert box to pop up. 
Do you have a live example that perhaps shows me how to do so? I appreciate it!

Comment: if you remove any lines of code which contain the `alert` or `prompt` command then the alert will not show up. It's that simple. Obviously you may need to find a different way to capture the user's input...but you didn't specify what kind of user interface you would prefer? Lots of people use things like HTML/CSS-powered modal dialogs, for example.

Comment: Thank you @ADyson, I literally just want to turn each slot in a text box so when the user clicks on a slot or selects multiple dates, he can just type a number on the keyboard and apply it to the selected slot(s) without the need to prompt a modal with a text input field.

Comment: You won't be able to do that. The main reason is that the "slots" you see on screen are actually an optical illusion made of multiple HTML tables layered on top of each other. So there's no definable space in the calendar markup where you could place a textbox. (this is in the TimeGrid view I'm talking about, which is where people mostly seem to use the selection feature, since it allows you to choose specific times of day. I guess you _could_ do it for the month or list views if you wanted to. But really I think you'll need to implement some sort of extra UI to capture extra fields e.g title)

Comment: @ADyson thanks for your reply. I do use the Monthly view but even with that, I haven't been able to make each day slot directly editable. It would be a good feature to add I guess.